# Need to expand $\nabla$ and $\Delta$ included term

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In this equation, they used $\nabla$ and $\Delta$, I need to expand them to understand this equation. More to see in this [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525) http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525 in equation (15)
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\ddot\phi_3+\phi_3+(p_1\Delta\alpha+2\nabla\alpha\nabla p_1)\sin(\tau+\alpha)
-\left[\Delta p_1+\omega_2p_1+\lambda p_1^3-p_1(\nabla\alpha)^2\right]
\cos(\tau+\alpha)\nonumber\\
&&+\frac{1}{12}p_1^3(2g_2^2+3g_3)\cos(3\tau+3\alpha)
+g_2p_1\left[q_2\sin(2\tau+2\alpha)+p_2\cos(2\tau+2\alpha)+p_2\right]
=0
\end{eqnarray}
where we have introduced the combination
\begin{equation}
\lambda=\frac{5}{6}g_2^2-\frac{3}{4}g_3 \,,
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec \nabla f = 
(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} , \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$)

$\vec \nabla f . \vec \nabla g = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} $

$\Delta f = \frac{\partial^2 f}{(\partial x)^2} +\frac{\partial^2 f}{(\partial y)^2} +\frac{\partial^2 f}{(\partial z)^2} $

Comment: Usually $\nabla f$ means $ (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})^T $ So I disagree with your first definition. The other two are correct.
Edit: However $\nabla \cdot f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$.

Comment: $\triangle f =  \nabla \cdot \nabla f$ sometimes written $\nabla^2 f$ aka the Laplacian. This answer is definitely missing some dot-products and vector notation. I'd downvote if not modified.

Comment: Your totally right for $\nabla f$, I was thinking of $\Delta f$ when writting...